# Plot Category Percentages Over Time

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I have a DataFrame with a datetime index and a software version column:

```
Date                   Version
2018-07-10 15:42:16    1.0
2018-07-10 16:38:18    1.0
2018-07-10 20:21:54    2.0
2018-07-11 08:28:56    1.0
2018-07-11 13:16:48    2.0
2018-07-13 15:25:56    2.0
```

I'd like to plot how many unique versions I have by time (say monthly) and what those versions are. I'm looking to plot this like a filled area plot over time. With the areas growing during adoption and decreasing when a new version rolls out.

Possibly like this but with time on the horizontal and version as the grouping.

https://python-graph-gallery.com/253-control-the-color-in-stacked-area-chart/

Answer (score 0):

you could do something like:

```
df.groupby('Version').resample('M').nunique()
```

or:

```
df.resample('d')['Version'].unique()
```

Answer (score 0):

try this, assuming the format of your data file is like above:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
dateparse = lambda x: pd.datetime.strptime(x, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S') 
data = pd.read_table(filename, parse_dates=['Date'], date_parser=dateparse)  # your file name 
data['month']  = data['Date'].dt.month.values; # can be year, etc. 
Months = data.groupby('month')['Version'].nunique().index.values 
nVersion = data.groupby('month')['Version'].nunique().values  
plt.fill_between(Months,0,nVersion)
plt.show()
```